# Merge multiple large dataframes in dask

Tags: python, dataframe, bigdata, dask

I have multiple (~50) large (~1 to 5gb each) csv files that I would like to merge into a single large csv file.
Using dask, I've created a loop that opens each csv and calls merge before saving everything to csv at the end of the loop:

```
for i, file in enumerate(files):

    table = dd.read_csv(file)
    if i == 0:
        merged = table
    else:
        merged = dd.merge(merged, table, on = ["id", "time", "key"])

merged.to_csv("merged\merged1810_*.csv")
```

However, doing so results in a `MemoryError`.

I though Dask was supposed to perform the computations in chunks to avoid these types of errors, is my data just too big for Dask to handle?
Is there any better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a full merge/join, or would a simple concat do?

```
df = dd.read_csv(files)
```

Doing full merge/joins can be quite expensive to do in parallel, especially in a low-memory situation.  It is very rare to see someone want to merge/join many dataframes iteratively like this.  I suspect that either `dd.read_csv` or `dd.concat` are likely better solutions for you.  (though I don't know your application)

Comment: I need an actual merge, not just a concat. What better solutions would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know some things on how your files/data are organized or are they completely random?

e.g could you easily re-arrange your csv files in several ones, with, say, one with all times per (id, key)?
Then you could sequentially merge each of those files and append to a bigger one? Assuming each "partition" fits in memory.

If you have not too many (id, key) pairs this could be manageable. I was facing a similar issue and ended up doing something like this and parallelized with dask. Might not be the most efficient/pretty but it got the job done...

Hope it helps,

Cheers